# need a regex to validate 'earn extra 20%' or 'earn 20% extra'

Tags: regex, go

Need a regex to validate following strings as mentioned.

```
'Earn extra 20%' - valid

'Earn 20% extra' - valid

'earn extra 20%' - valid

'earn 20% extra' - valid

'Earn 20' - valid

'Earn ' - Invalid

'20' - Invalid

'Earn ^&' - Invalid
```

any other special characters should not be allowed

-using golang 1.19

Comment: Do you want to match only `20` or any number between 0-100, or something else?

Comment: any number can be entered

Comment: Are the single-quotation marks part of the value?

Comment: no no, just to differentiate

Comment: So `"Earn 1000000% extra"` is OK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `(?i)` (case insensitive) flag and an alternation with optional terms (instead of using look arounds, which go doesn't support):

```
(?i)earn (\d+%?( extra)?|extra \d+%?)
```

See [live regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/GB2VQmwMbFtXLl).

See [live go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/jjxqoVnq1Gd).

Comment: didn't want to hard code earn/extra. want to keep it generic so that if a user tries entering some other text it should support that.

Comment: for example: 'get 20rs extra'

Comment: @Dev for a regex you'll need to be able to specify what is allowed and what isn't down to every space and letter. Regex rules are strict, they don't understand natural language. You can either allow any letter combination like "earn 20xg fnahjt" or you need to put an exact word/character list in the regex. Alternatively run some preprocessing step to replace all the allowed words & characters with a "normalized" version that your regex looks for (replace "get" with "earn" and "rs" with "%" etc)

Comment: understood but atleast we can make the percentage amount generic, can't restrict to 20.

Comment: @Dev answer updated to allow any number. If you want to allow more options of text, update the question with a list (formatted as code) of examples that should match, and another list of examples that should not match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
regex := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?=.*\bEarn\b|\bearn\b)(?=.*\b\d+\b|%)(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9%\s])`)
```

Testing: https://regex101.com/r/axGrst/1

Comment: didn't want to hard code earn/extra. want to keep it generic so that if a user tries entering some other text it should support that.

Comment: for example: 'get 20rs extra'

Comment: Go doesn't support lookarounds.

Answer (score -1):

Try below,

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*(?i)earn[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*(?i)extra[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*20%?[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)
```

This will match -

1. String which must have earn, extra and 20 in string
2. With or without % after 20
3. Other words should not contain the special character (only numbers and normal characters are allowed)

Comment: not able to validate 'Earn extra 20%'

Comment: @Dev With few changes it is showing an expected result as per test cases in the question please check here - https://regex101.com/r/no614X/1 The new RegEx - ^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_ %]*(?i)earn|extra[a-zA-Z0-9_ %]*)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_ %]*20%?[a-zA-Z0-9_ %]*)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).